# SQL server 2005 group by with same column but different date and time?

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2005, grouping

everyone ...currently i have a table as below ..

```
DATE               BATCHNO     PRODCODE
----------------------------------------------
31/12/2009 23.53    10859       2003P
01/01/2010 00.04    10860       2003P
01/01/2010 00.06    10861       2003P
01/01/2010 00.13    10862       2003P
01/01/2010 00.30    10863       1259
01/01/2010 03.02    10864       639B
01/01/2010 03.13    10865       639B
01/01/2010 03.20    10866       639B
01/01/2010 04.13    10867       2003P
01/01/2010 04.20    10868       2003P
01/01/2010 04.30    10863       2003P
```

above is the example of the table i have now.. the DATE is generated whenever there are new BATCHNO and the BATCHNO is increase by 1 .. the PRODCODE is the code of the product where machine manufacture the product and let say product 2003P finished manufactured, it will automatically go for another product such as 1259...

i would like to compute those data into the below desired result:

```
DATE               PRODCODE
----------------------------------------------
31/12/2009 23.53     2003P
01/01/2010 00.13     2003P
01/01/2010 00.30     1259
01/01/2010 00.30     1259
01/01/2010 03.02     639B
01/01/2010 03.20     639B  
01/01/2010 04.13     2003P
01/01/2010 04.30     2003P
```

meaning that 31/12/2009 23.53 is the start time for the product 2003P and 01/01/2012 00.13 is the stop time for product 2003P.. and for product 1259 is special because 01/01/2010 00.30 only produce 1 product before move to other product..basically i cant use group by because it will group by all the product which are the same code .. the problem is that detect the start time and stop time for the particular product code. . how can this be accomplished? and this is for SQL SERVER 2005 ...

thanks everyone ..

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
select U.[DATE], U.PRODCODE
from
  (
    select min(T.[DATE]) as StartDate,
           max(T.[DATE]) as EndDate,
           T.PRODCODE
    from 
      (
        select [DATE],
               PRODCODE,
               row_number() over(order by [DATE]) as rn1,
               row_number() over(order by PRODCODE, [DATE]) as rn2
        from YourTable
      ) T
    group by T.PRODCODE, T.rn2-T.rn1
  ) T
unpivot
  (
    [DATE] for D in (StartDate, EndDate)
  ) U
order by U.[DATE]
```

[SE-Data](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/70711/sql-server-2005-group-by-with-same-column-but-different-date-and-time)

Comment: I think you can't guarantee that rows sorted by `PRODCODE` will automatically be sorted by `[DATE]` where `PRODCODE` is the same. You'll need to add `[DATE]` as a sort criterion explicitly: `row_number() over(order by PRODCODE, [DATE]) as rn2`.

Comment: thanks for both of you ..meaning that above query is correct?

Comment: @newbieHQ As far as I can tell, yes it should work. I have modified the query according to the comment by AndriyM.

Comment: i tested the query...and it works fine ! thank you for helping me a lot ... and i am still have long way to go ...... haha....have a nice day !

Answer (score 2):

Idea: add a column to get the id of the next DIFFERENT piece start time and remove and query to fill it. Then create another column, but this time save the previous DIFFERENT piece end time. The code for such a task would be a subquery

```
update table set 
    prev=(select top 1 batchno from table x where x.prodcode!=table.prodcode  and x.date<table.date order by x.date DESC)+1, 
    next=(select top 1 batchno from table x where x.prodcode!=table.prodcode and x.date>table.date order by x.date ASC)-1
```

this way you would have the boundaries for each product. From now you just

```
select prodcode, prev, next from table group by prodcode, prev, next
```

and finally join up dates from table on the last query on `prev=prodcode` and `next=prodcode`.

Good luck :)